# DecisionTreeRegressor with criterion='poisson' not recognizing perfect separation

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees

I created a minimal example of Poisson decision tree regression as such

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn import tree

X = np.array([
    [1,1,2,2,2],
    [0,0,0,1,1],
]).T

y = np.array([2,2,10,10,10])

regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='poisson')
regressor.fit(X, y)

_ = tree.plot_tree(regressor, filled=True)
```

[image: Tree result]

I expected the tree to immediately recognize `X[0]` as being the best predictor that separates `y` cleanly, but the tree decides to separate using `X[1]` prior to `X[0]`. Is there a reason why the tree prefers `X[1]` instead of `X[0]`? The behavior does not appear when `criterion='squared_error'`.

Answer (score 1):

When using the code above, with scikit-learn 1.2.2 (released in March 2023), I get the expected result:

[image]

It could have been a matter of the package's version and the corrections made in the meantime (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v1.2.html#).

I was able to reproduce your result when using:

```
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='poisson', max_features=1)
```